# A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process

Tags: bdc, certificate, external-data

My 2016 SharePoint farm, among other servers/services, runs two Front Ends and has Business Data Connectivity setup. I have created an external data source to a SQL server database and an External Content Type via SharePoint Designer. With that, I have created an External List on a site. The two front ends are load balanced.

On one FrontEnd, I can access the external list data by navigating to it in the browser. However, when I am load-balanced to the other Front End, I get the error "A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process." with a further message in the ULS logs saying "The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted". I have compared the certificates, trusted and otherwise on both front ends and the SQL servers. Everything appears in order. I have ensured both front end's bindings are correct to the appropriate sites.

I can't seem to figure out why when load-balanced to one front end it works, but refuses to work on the other. I'm wondering if there is some web.config item that is off or if there is a registry setting messed up somewhere. Has anyone see this or had experience with this in general?

Comment: Try enabling the CAPI2 log in the Event Log to see what the error with the cert is.

Comment: SSL self-signed fallback provided by the SQL server that I'm querying the external data from. The front end that works returns nothing from that server.

Comment: Did you enable the CAPI2 log to get more information?

Comment: @TrevorSeward Yes, what I wrote was what I was seeing in the CAPI2 log. The front end that doesn't work receives an error with Event ID 30. The certificate referenced in the error is a self-signed certificate direct from the SQL server I am pulling external data from. Nothing like that shows up on the front end that does work.